# Leaflet: added GeoJSON Feature to FeatureGroup doesn't show up

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have a geojsonLayer and a selectionLayer. I want to add specific features to the selectionLayer after a click event.

I create the selectionLayer at startup:

```
selectionLayer = new .FeatureGroup().setStyle(selectionStyle).addTo(map);
```

To the geojson layer I bind:

```
layer.on({
    click: featureClick
})
```

Which contains:

```
function featureClick(event) {
    event.target.addTo(selectionLayer)
}
```

This workes though, when I check `selectionLayer.getLayers().length`, the feature is added. But they doesn't show up on the map at all.

Answer (score 3):

> ... But they doesn't show up on the map at all.

They do... because *they're already on the map*, as part of your `L.GeoJSON` group.

(I'm assuming that you have a `L.GeoJSON` added to the map, as you're reacting to `click` events on it).

Your GeoJSON features have been converted into a `L.Layer` (either `L.Marker`s, `L.Polyline`s or `L.Polygons`) by the magic of `L.GeoJSON` - and those layers have received a style and have been added to the map - by the `L.GeoJSON` instance.

The issue here is a misunderstanding of what [`setStyle`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#featuregroup-setstyle) does here at

```
new L.FeatureGroup().setStyle(selectionStyle)
```

The `setStyle` method calls `setStyle` on any layers that are part of the group, **but only at the time when `setStyle` is called**. By the tone of your question, I assume that you *expect* `selectionStyle` to be applied to layers *when they're added to that group*, which does not happen by design.

Keep in mind that in Leaflet a `L.Layer` can be part of any number of `L.LayerGroup`/`L.FeatureGroup`s. It's perfectly possible to do something like

```
var line = L.polyline(...);
var group1 = L.featureGroup().addTo(map).addLayer(line);
var group2 = L.featureGroup().addTo(map).addLayer(line);
```

(Which is what's happening in your case, but with one instance of `L.GeoJSON` and one of `L.FeatureGroup`).

If you want to change the styling of any `L.Layer` (on hover/click/selection/etc), do so explicitly. The [Leaflet tutorial on interactive chloropeths](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) has details on a way to do that. **Adding layers to a `L.FeatureGroup` will not trigger any re-styling**.

Comment: I got it to run.
`function featureClick(event) {
    var polygon = event.target;
    polygon.addTo(selectionLayer);
    selectionLayer.setStyle(selectionStyle(polygon.feature));
}`